# How to imbed grid of 6 youtube videos with dynamic one above on clicking?

Tags: html, css, youtube, grid

I want to imbed some 6 youtube videos to my website and when one is clicked for it to play above the overs like in the photo below.

How how do I make it so that when a video is clicked it plays above like in the 2nd photo.

[Before any video is clicked they are like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsuce.jpg)

[Once a video is clicked the grid looks like this, with the clicked video playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERaYb.jpg)

[What I would like my display to look like when a video is clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjc9L.png)

Currently I just have my 6 videos in a grid. And the part I am stuck on is how to get the clicked video to open up above and start playing at same width of the div that contains the videos below.

```
        <div class="grid">
      <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bk6Xst6euQk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-5EQIiabJvk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2loN0JFZa0Y" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fKFbnhcNnjE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hC8CH0Z3L54" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HIXwkduDI3w" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And a little CSS I have is here:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}


.iframe-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

EDIT: I think my previous approach was totally wrong. I think the solution is something like this:

1. Have a grid 6 images, the image can be the youtube preview image of a video.
2. When an image is clicked, a container opens up above containing an iframe, the URL feb into the iframe is of the respective video.
3. Clicking the image again closes the iframe. Clicking another image
   starts that one to play.

Comment: Do you have code sample from your site that shows what you're working with?

Comment: you should provide the code of the css and html if you have. Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/tour. thanks..

Comment: @ssd is that your site, or just an example? If the latter then your question is too broad, we don't know what you have currently.

Comment: @Tom I have updated the original post to show my current code. 
The part I am stuck on is how to get the clicked video to open up above the grid of 6 and start playing.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expect? Click of a link opens a youtube video.
http://jsfiddle.net/ZcMk

```js
function toggleVideo(state) {
    // if state == 'hide', hide. Else: show video
    var div = document.getElementById("popupVid");
    var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    div.style.display = state == 'hide' ? 'none' : '';
    func = state == 'hide' ? 'pauseVideo' : 'playVideo';
    iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}','*');
}
```

```html
<p><a href="javascript:;" onClick="toggleVideo();">Click here</a> to play your favourite video.</p>

<!-- popup and contents -->
<div id="popupVid" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:87px;width:500px;background-color:#D05F27;height:auto;display:none;z-index:200;">
   <iframe width="500" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/T39hYJAwR40?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   <br /><br />
   <a href="javascript:;" onClick="toggleVideo('hide');">close</a>
```